# How do I save a file as .pig using windows?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

I just tried running a Elastic MapReduce job using a Pig script.  I created the Pig script in Notepad, saved it originally as a .txt file, then manually changed the extension to .pig and uploaded.  Here's the error I got:

Run Pig Script  FAILED  2013-04-24 08:58 CDT    2013-04-24 08:59 CDT    s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar  -   s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/pig-script --run-pig-script --pig-versions latest --args -p INPUT=s3n://cse6242-?gtcse-?data/gb-?bigrams/ -p OUTPUT=s3n://cse02-bones6/pigoutput/ s3n://cse02-bones6/pigsample/pigscript.pig

Those ?'s in the INPUT look fishy to me.  What is the issue here, and is there a problem with the way I created the .pig file?

Comment: The only non-letter characters are dashes.  That is the entire error.

Comment: You can rename files in S3... have you tried renaming the file to verify if the name is the issue? How are you executing the pig script and where are you getting this error? Have you tried starting an EMR job with logging enabled?